# Django Rest Framework + React JWT authentication, 403 Forbidden on protected views

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm trying to make a CRUD website with DRF + react, i've somewhat followed this tutorial for authentication

https://hackernoon.com/110percent-complete-jwt-authentication-with-django-and-react-2020-iejq34ta
(with some differences since i'm using DRF and React completely separatedly)

authentication is fine, i can already login, logout and signup, however any view that requires the permission "IsAuthenticated" gets me a 403 Forbidden, i've tried to also get the data through postman using the headers:
 Accept : application/json
 Authorization :  JWT "myaccesstoken"
but i also get a 403 with "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."

Here's some of the code

```
Settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', (#I've already tried commenting out basic and session auth)
    )
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=14),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT ',),
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'username',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

And the protected view

```
views.py
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,) (#I've tried with or without this)
    authentication_classes = () (# if i take this out i get a 401 insteand of a 403)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

I'm not showing any of the react code since i think the problem is in the DRF part since i can't make the GET request succesfully on PostMan either, if i change the settings to AllowAny i can make the GET requests in both places just fine

Comment: At first glance, once difference I see in what you have versus the tutorial is that under `'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES'` you've put `'JWT '` with a space, whereas they haven't included a space there. Not 100% sure if this will fix your problem but as I understand it, spaces in HTTP headers do matter.

Comment: Just changed it but i get the same error

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. It seems that REST_FRAMEWORK settings, for default authentication (specifically rest_framework_simplejwt) does not work. I don't know why...

Try to directly import JWTAuthentication class in your authentication_classes tuple like :

```py
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
class PostList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for answering my old question, I've since given up on that project so I don't have that old code but I'm now just working on another one trying the same authentication, I've just managed to make this work by using the dj-rest-auth package which optionally comes with simple-jwt integration!.